# How to get selected value/text from HTML Select in codebehind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to get my selected value/text from and HTML select option but I can't get it! I already tried with answers posted in this website but none works.

This my code:

```
<select id="Select" name="Select" runat="server">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

I tried these C# codes:

```
//With this I get Index out of range error message:
string name = nombre.Items[nombre.SelectedIndex].Text;
//With this I get nothing:
string name = this.nombre.Value.ToString();
//Nothing here:
string name = this.nombre.Value;
```

What can I do? It's necessary using html select control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get a value,

```
string sVal = dropdownName.Items[dropdownName.SelectedIndex].Value;
```

to get a text,

```
string sText= dropdownName.Items[dropdownName.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Comment: if Dropdownlist is HTML control then how dropdownName can be accessed from C#?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using an asp:DropDownList, but you can still reference straight selects.  Here's code that will grab the value and text from your HTML above:

```
string value = Select.Items[Select.SelectedIndex].Value;
string text = Select.Items[Select.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Be sure you're using the correct ID name (Select is shown in your html, but nombre is used in your code behind).

Comment: I need to use html controls, but what I did was create a hidden textbox and with javascript I set the selectedvalue to that textbox and in C# I only do nombre.text and that's it! That id names was a copy paste mistake. Anyway, thanks for your help